# SQL UPDATE only Duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-update, inner-join

I have a SQL Table like this:

```
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
| id   | x          | y       | z       | status |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
|    1 |        bla |      ja | 1       |   0    |
|    2 |       blaa |     jaa | 2       |   0    |
|    3 |        bla |      ja | 1       |   0    |
|    4 |      blaaa |    jaaa | 3       |   0    |
|    5 |       blaa |     jaa | 2       |   0    |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

I want to UPDATE only the status column of the duplicate rows and not the first one.

With that statement i update every duplicate also the first row of a duplicate row:

```
UPDATE table INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT x, y, z FROM table GROUP BY x,y,z HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) 
dup
        ON table.x = dup.x && table.y = dup.y && table.z = dup.z 
    SET status = '1'
```

But thats no right because the table has to look after the UPDATE Statement like this:

```
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
| id   | x          | y       | z       | status |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
|    1 |        bla |      ja | 1       |   0    |
|    2 |       blaa |     jaa | 2       |   0    |
|    3 |        bla |      ja | 1       |   1    |
|    4 |      blaaa |    jaaa | 3       |   0    |
|    5 |       blaa |     jaa | 2       |   1    |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Answer (score 1):

Just play with a select statment like the one below until you have a list of the duplicates then update as shown.

```
UPDATE table set status = '1'
WHERE ID in (select id from(Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By x,y,z,status) as dup,id) where dup>1)
```

Didn't say RDBMS so this is for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
UPDATE table t INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT x, y, z, MIN(id) as minid
        FROM table
        GROUP BY x, y, z
        HAVING COUNT(id) > 1  -- not strictly necessary, but why not?
       ) dup
       ON t.x = dup.x AND t.y = dup.y AND t.z = dup.z AND
          t.id > dup.minid
    SET status = 1;
```

This calculates the minimum `id` for each group and then updates all the other rows.

Comment: One more question: Is it possible to put the ID from the each first original entry to the each duplicates ?

Comment: @wp-developer . . . Of course.  Just use `minid` in the `set`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.